# How to use integrated graphics instead dedicated(gpu)?

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, gpu, integrated

I have an Intel Pentium G4560 and Geforce GTX 1050... I need use the gpu for virtualbox... But before that I need to set host OS (Ubuntu) to the integrated graphics instead gpu.
How achieve that? My monitor is plugged to gpu, I need to change it to onboard?

Comment: It seems that you are talking about PCI-passthrough. As I know it is supported only with QEMU/KVM - see something like https://blog.zerosector.io/2018/07/28/kvm-qemu-windows-10-gpu-passthrough/ .

Comment: When set intel_iommu=on ubuntu do not boot (Intel vt-D activated in BIOS)